# Question about the definition of a vector field on a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I am reading do Carmo's *Riemannian Geometry,* and he defines the tangent bundle $TM$ of a differentiable manifold $M$ as $\{ (p, v) : p \in M, v \in T_pM\}.$ That's fine. Next, he defines (on page 25):

> A *vector field* $X$ on a differentiable manifold $M$ is a
> correspondence that associates to each point $p \in M$ a vector $X(p)$
> $\in T_pM$. In terms of mappings, $X$ is a mapping of $M$ into the
> tangent bundle $TM$. The field is called *differentiable* if the
> mapping $X: M \to TM$ is differentiable.

So on one hand, he is saying that $X(p) \in T_p M$, which means that $X(p)$ is some tangent vector $v$. However, he then says that $X$ maps into $TM$, which means that $X(p) = (p, v)$ for some $v \in T_p M$. Am I missing something, or is he contradicting himself?

Comment: What he says is fine; $X$ is a map from $M$ to $TM$ which satisfies the property that $X(p) \in TM_p$, the tangent space of $M$ at $m \in M$. When you say $X(p)=v$, that is a point in $T_pM$, but if you view it as a point in $TM$, then one normally write it as $(p,v)$, as otherwise it is not clear what tangent space it is to be understood to lie in.

Comment: Each point $p$ has its own tangent space $T_p$. This is just saying that a vector field assigns a tangent vector to each point in the manifold. An even more compact way to say it is that a vector field is a section of the tangent bundle. They all mean the same thing as the first definition.

Comment: Th e tangent bundle $TM$ is the disjoint union of the tangent spaces $T_p(M)$ as $p$ varies across the manifold.  Each is a vector space at that point and the vector field is just selecting a vector from each.  More formally, since each tangent space is a subset of $TM$, it can be viewed as  function from $p$ to $T_p(M) \subset TM$. Probably just all the terminology and notation obscuring a relatively basic idea.

Comment: @krm2233 When you say $X$ is a map to $TM$, it means that the output of $X$ has the form $(p, v)$. When you say $X(p) \in T_pM$, it means the output of $X$ has the form $v$. Sorry but how is that not contradictory?

Comment: It's a common slight abuse of notation in the field, no surprise you've noticed it if you like formal syntax/langauges (like me). Sometimes geometers write tangent vectors as $v\in T_xM$, sometimes $(p,v)\in TM$, but they refer to the same object. Depends on what you want to _stress_. The context always makes it clear so you shouldn't have difficulties understanding the material because of it. Don't get too picky about it :)

Comment: @user56202 do Carmo is trying to informally introduce a vector field when he writes "it is a correspondence that associates to each point $p \in M$ a tangent vector $v\in T_pM$." He then gives a formal definition saying it is a function $X\colon M \to TM$ with the property that $X(p) = (p,v) \in T_pM \subseteq TM$. At worst he is using a standard abuse of notation.

Comment: @krm2233 Ok, so if the abuse of notation is that tangent vectors are sometimes considered to be $(p, v)$ and sometimes just $v$, then I understand. I wasn't aware of this.

Comment: @Al.G. Thanks a lot, it makes a lot more sense now!

Comment: To put it another way, the abuse, I suspect, long predates do Carmo, so it is harsh to shoot the messenger. The ambiguity goes back, I expect, to the following:  If you think of a surface $S$ in $\mathbb R^3$, and its tangent space at some point $p \in S$, then almost everyone pictures a 2-plane at the point $p\in S$, i.e. an affine plane in $\mathbb R^3$, and not the parallel vector subspace.

Comment: @Al.G. Like with a lot of mathematical notation, the standard abuses are context-dependent: if you say "tangent vector $v$" and it is clear from context that you were referring to a vector in a particular tangent space $T_pM$, then writing "$v$" is sufficient. If you said out of the blue, "suppose $v$ is tangent to the sphere $S^2$", then I'd probably ask "tangent where?", and you would have to write $v \in T_pS^2$, or just $(p,v) \in TS^2$.

Comment: Yes, I fully agree. At some point I had to unlearn the 100% formallity/syntax correctness I was taught at first just because it becomes impractical in most cases (and in the real world people can get annoyed). Usually common sense gets you far enough.

Comment: @Al.G. That's interesting. I have taken classes just as advanced (or more advanced) than this Intro to Differential Geometry class, including applied classes like Optimization and Numerical Analysis, and I have seen very little (if any) abuse of notation. Pretty much everything has been syntactically 100% correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntactically, if $X:M\to TM$ is a vector field and $p\in M$, then $X(p)=(p,v)$ for some $v\in T_p M$ because $TM$ is a *disjoint* union of all $T_p M$'s, i.e. formally an object like $\bigcup_p \{p\}\times T_p M$ (but if you write it like this you should specify the proper topology that is meant).

But remember that $X$ is a *section*, i.e. $\pi \circ X=\textrm{id}$. This means that $X$ always sends $p$ to some pair $(p,\cdot)$, so the first element of it is readily determined. So in some sense it is redundant to write $X(p)=(p,v)\in \{p\}\times T_p M$ and we just write $X(p)=v\in T_p M$, slightly abusing notation for brevity.

It's nice to see someone else got puzzled by this too (like I was in the beginning). Rest assured, it's easy to get over it, as it never really causes any problems.